# use regex to get all attributes

Tags: php, regex

My input string is

```
$center="[{video('whats-new/reaction-vid1.jpg')} width=\"580\" height=\"326\" alt=\"\" video=\"Zb36h4K2IKQ\"]";
$pattern="/\[{video\('([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\_]+)'\)}\s+(width|height|alt|video)=\"[^\"]+\"\]/";
if(preg_match($pattern,$center,$matches)){
   print_r($matches);exit;
}
```

However it is not working. Basically i want to extra attributes for width, height, alt and video.I have tried half an hour. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean **two** extra attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
$center="[{video('whats-new/reaction-vid1.jpg')} width=\"580\" height=\"326\" alt=\"\" video=\"Zb36h4K2IKQ\"]";
$pattern="~video\('\K[^']*|(?:width|height|alt|video)=\"\K[^\"]*~";
preg_match_all($pattern, $center, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => whats-new/reaction-vid1.jpg
            [1] => 580
            [2] => 326
            [3] => 
            [4] => Zb36h4K2IKQ
        )

)
```

Comment: sorry, what is the meaning of ~video here, as $center is a variable sentence, it may have valeus such as "abcded [{video('whats-new/reaction-vid1.jpg')} width=\"580\" height=\"326\" alt=\"\" video=\"Zb36h4K2IKQ\"]gef"

Comment: regex pattern must be enclosed within delimiters. I enclosed the above regex pattern within `~`

Comment: i tried, seem ur solution also able to handle "abcded [{video('whats-new/reaction-vid1.jpg')} width=\"580\" height=\"326\" alt=\"\" video=\"Zb36h4K2IKQ\"]gef" cases, thanks

Comment: Actually i have one more question. in this case, after got all the preg_match_all values, i want to replace the input string to "" so i can reformat the values into html structure such as <img src=""width="" height=""alt="" /> and there are quite a few occurences of the input strings in a real content, is there any call back function to do this

Comment: originally i am using if(preg_match_all($pattern, $center, $matches)){$input=preg_replace($pattern, "", $input);} but seem not working

Comment: @onegun ask it as another question.

Comment: hi avinash, new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112544/preg-match-all-and-then-replace-for-an-input-string