# Preg_match_all and then replace for an input string

Tags: php, regex

Basically I want to parse some input contents which have some syntax then convert to html codes.

e.g.

```
$input="Please watch video 1 [{video('whats-new/chain_reaction-vid1.jpg')} width="580" 
height="326" alt="" video="Zb36h4K2IKQ"] and video 2 [{video('whats-new/chain_reaction-
vid2.jpg')} width="580" height="326" alt="" video="Zb36h4K2IDY"] . Enjoy.";
```

Currently there is a way to extra all attributes for video using,

```
$pattern="/video\('\K[^']*|(?:width|height|alt|video)=\"\K[^\"]*/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

although I am able to get the `$matches`, it seems hard to replace.

`[{video('whats-new/chain_reaction-vid1.jpg')} width="580" height="326" alt="" video="Zb36h4K2IKQ"]`

with some call back functions to convert this part into appropriate html such as

`<a href="youtube.com/Zb36h4K2IKQ"><img src="whats-new/chain_reaction-vid1.jpg" width="580" height="326" alt=""></a>`

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
\[{video\('([^']*)'\)}([^\]]*)\s+video="([^"]*)"]
```

**Replacement string:**

```
<a href="youtube.com/$3"><img src="$1"$2></a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yO6gJ5/2)

```
<?php
$input='Please watch video 1 [{video(\'whats-new/chain_reaction-vid1.jpg\')} width="580" 
height="326" alt="" video="Zb36h4K2IKQ"] and video 2 [{video(\'whats-new/chain_reaction-
vid2.jpg\')} width="580" height="326" alt="" video="Zb36h4K2IDY"] . Enjoy.';
echo preg_replace("~\[{video\('([^']*)'\)}([^\]]*)\s+video=\"([^\"]*)\"]~", '<a href="youtube.com/$3"><img src="$1"$2></a>', $input)
?>
```

Output:

```
Please watch video 1 <a href="youtube.com/Zb36h4K2IKQ"><img src="whats-new/chain_reaction-vid1.jpg" width="580" 
height="326" alt=""></a> and video 2 <a href="youtube.com/Zb36h4K2IDY"><img src="whats-new/chain_reaction-
vid2.jpg" width="580" height="326" alt=""></a> . Enjoy.
```

Comment: thanks, should i use preg_match_all or preg_replace? also there are multiple video in an input

Comment: $pattern="/\[{video\('([^']*)'\)}([^\]]*)\s+video=\"([^\"]*)\"]/gm";
            if(preg_match($pattern,$center,$matches)){
                $center=preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="youtube.com/$3"><img src="$1"$2></a>', $center);
            } saying error Message: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: added some codes..don't use g modifier in code. It's already enabled in php.

Comment: yes, guys, appreciate. actually i am wondering, how to handle the error if preg_replace fail?

Comment: also @avinash Raj, why dont you escape \] at the end of the pattern

Comment: opening `[` must be escaped to mean a literal `[` symbol, but escaping of `]` is not needed if we correctly enclosed the character class.